# I can't build HELLO, WORLD program?

Tags: c, gcc, netbeans, compiler-errors

I am new to learning C and I'm on Windows (I want to learn on Windows).

I have installed GCC on cygwin, and I'm using **NetBeans IDE**.

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I get this **error** when building the above code:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/g/VS Projects/Hello World'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/hello_world.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/g/VS Projects/Hello World'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/helloworld.o.d
gcc    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/helloworld.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/helloworld.o helloworld.c
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
gcc     -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/hello_world build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/helloworld.o  build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o 
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/g/VS Projects/Hello World/main.c:14: multiple definition of `main'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/helloworld.o:/cygdrive/g/VS Projects/Hello World/helloworld.c:4: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:63: recipe for target `dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/hello_world.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/hello_world.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/g/VS Projects/Hello World'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:60: recipe for target `.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/g/VS Projects/Hello World'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target `.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 562ms)
```

**Is there any simple way to learn C on Windows?** (visual studio gave me errors and seems to be mainly for c++, so that's not an option)

Comment: look at the error message: main.c line 14 - multiple definition of main

Comment: You're building it using Netbeans.  Have you tried compiling using the command line?

Comment: Incidentally, `main()` should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely to be with your `gcc` or your NetBeans configuration

It's working fine here

```c
// helloworld.c
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compile to `myprog`

```
$ gcc helloworld.c -o myprog
```

Run it

```
$ ./myprog
# => Hello, world!
```

Comment: I always use `make helloworld` :-)

Comment: @meaning-matters that requires a `Makefile` to be written. For the purposes of this example, I'm keeping things as straightforward as possible.

Comment: Don't trick newbie, by `&& ./hello` if OP don't know how to compile and execute. Else it need an explanation

Comment: @naomik No, you don't need a `Makefile` because there are default rules.  Did you try it?  But for the sake of clarity in this answer, it's better the way you did it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at how your NetBeans is set up.  The compilation that is failing is:

```
gcc -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/hello_world \
       build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/helloworld.o \
       build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o
```

There are two object files there; one looks like the object file for your `helloworld.c` with its `main()`, and another is the object file for a file `main.c` which presumably also contains a `main()` program.

Redefine your build rules so that you don't link `main.o` into your executable.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post but you should look at the project's Source Files. There, NetBeans produces by default 2 main.c files. Erase one of them, leaving only one, and then try to build the project again.